# Assert that all values are negative or all values are non-negative

Tags: python

I need to assert that all numeric values in an array are either negative or non-negative.

I wrote this:

```
def check(arr):
    return all([i < 0 for i in arr]) or all([i >= 0 for i in arr])
```

And this, which is slightly more efficient I suppose:

```
def check(arr):
    temp = [i < 0 for i in arr]
    return all(temp) or not any(temp)
```

I would like to know if there's a cleaner / more pythonic way, or perhaps some arithmetic trick which I can use instead.

Comment: You can check any element is thesame with the rest `all(x == temp[0] for x in temp)` but using numpy would be the easiest

Comment: @percusse But that's not what OP wants

Comment: @DeepSpace It works for the second example

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a set comprehension to derive a `set` of Boolean values. This `set` will be either `{True}`, `{False}` or `{True, False}`. Then test if your `set` has length equal to 1.

```
def check(arr):
    return len({i < 0 for i in arr}) == 1
```

Comment: Create a `dict` and making sure it doesn't contain both `true` and `false`?

Comment: @goodvibration, I think a `dict` may be overkill here.

Comment: Nice, and with a single iteration